# Java application monitoring using SNMP

Tags: java, linux, snmp

I have a java application running on production servers (all linux OS). I want to use SNMP to monitor the java on production servers. Is there any posibility to use SNMP for java applicaiton monitoring. Following are the contents i am interested in.

**Java Monitoring**

```
a) Mmemory in use.
b) Memory utilisation -- Threads
c) Java process Memory Utilisation
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can do this. You need SNMP agent embedded into your application. Try this link for example: http://www.snmp4j.org/.

BTW are you sure you really need SNMP? Didn't you think about JMX instead?

Comment: Thanks Alex, I need the SNMP only.

Comment: @Space I'd also recommend using SNMP4J for interacting with SNMP agents on remote machines, but in my opinion it better fits communication with network devices (routers, servers and so on). For monitoring JVM, I'd definitely use JMX, as AlexR suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You also can try to use [SNMP agent embedded into JavaVM](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/snmp.html).